# Access rename information, e.g. in `git show`, programmatically

Tags: git, libgit2

Take for example

```
> git show 9c1cb268c2895fca1a8036c82f5448816cb95510
commit 9c1cb268c2895fca1a8036c82f5448816cb95510
Author: Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>
Date:   Thu Jul 21 17:10:24 2022 -0400

    Renamed files.

diff --git a/baz.py b/bag.py
similarity index 100%
rename from baz.py
rename to bag.py
diff --git a/run_baz.bat b/run_bag.bat
similarity index 80%
rename from run_baz.bat
rename to run_bag.bat
index e660f46..e06d1f0 100644
--- a/run_baz.bat
+++ b/run_bag.bat
@@ -17,6 +17,6 @@
[...]
```

I would like to extract the information about renaming and similarity index in a structured and reliable way (e.g. robust to filenames with spaces in them).

The output above appears to be generated by [this code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c48035d29b4e524aed3a32f0403676f0d9128863/diff.c#L4373-L4393).

What `libgit2` function or other computer-friendly interface can I use to access this? I understand that this information is not directly represented in the git repository (which in essence only stores snapshots of the files), but instead generated as needed for human consumption.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What programming/scripting language must this work for (libgit2 implies C)? Do you need to query this per file (it's history) or per commit? Can can show this with a pseudo code command and an example of desired output?

Comment: The bounty mentions: "Ideally, I would like a simple way to access this information from Python, with the use of package such as pygit2."

For a given commit, I would like the move/rename/copy information with filenames. Furthermore, I want the filenames delimited such that I can parse them even if there are spaces (or other kinds of valid characters) in them.

Comment: In other words you'll accept a solution in ***any*** language but will favor one for the bounty if it's python?  If not you should make that clear in the question and add the `python` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that [git-diff-tree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree) is what you're looking for:

```
$ git log --stat --summary -1 HEAD
commit 9de8e454e8ccabf332ea249cbe56185f1c6ba465
Author: Test <test@example.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 16 22:16:02 2022 -0800

    b

 a => b | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename a => b (100%)
$ git ls-tree HEAD
100644 blob d6459e005434a49a66a3ddec92279a86160ad71f    b
$ git ls-tree HEAD^ 
100644 blob d6459e005434a49a66a3ddec92279a86160ad71f    a
$ git diff-tree --find-copies-harder -r -M HEAD^ HEAD
:100644 100644 d6459e005434a49a66a3ddec92279a86160ad71f d6459e005434a49a66a3ddec92279a86160ad71f R100   a   b
```

`d6459e005434a49a66a3ddec92279a86160ad71f` is the blob ID of the file `b`, which has been renamed from from `a`. `R100` tells you that it has been renamed with 100 similarity.

An example from [VLC](https://github.com/videolan/vlc/commit/126fb1184cbc3e9716a903655f71fe45b85d2fb6):

```
$ git log --stat --summary -1 --find-copies-harder 126fb1184cbc3e9716a903655f71fe45b85d2fb6
commit 126fb1184cbc3e9716a903655f71fe45b85d2fb6
Author: Felix Paul Kühne <fkuehne@videolan.org>
Date:   Sun Jun 10 11:36:51 2018 +0200

    macosx: split windows file to have one class per file

 extras/package/macosx/VLC.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj      |  30 +++++++++++++++++------
 modules/gui/macosx/Makefile.am                           |   3 ++-
 modules/gui/macosx/VLCFSPanelController.h                |   2 +-
 modules/gui/macosx/VLCMainWindow.h                       |   2 +-
 modules/gui/macosx/{Windows.h => VLCVideoWindowCommon.h} |  26 ++------------------
 modules/gui/macosx/{Windows.m => VLCVideoWindowCommon.m} | 174 +++-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 modules/gui/macosx/{VLCApplication.h => VLCWindow.h}     |  28 +++++++++++++++------
 modules/gui/macosx/VLCWindow.m                           | 195 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 po/POTFILES.in                                           |   6 +++--
 9 files changed, 252 insertions(+), 214 deletions(-)
 rename modules/gui/macosx/{Windows.h => VLCVideoWindowCommon.h} (80%)
 rename modules/gui/macosx/{Windows.m => VLCVideoWindowCommon.m} (85%)
 copy modules/gui/macosx/{VLCApplication.h => VLCWindow.h} (65%)
 create mode 100644 modules/gui/macosx/VLCWindow.m
$ $ git diff-tree --find-copies-harder -r 126fb1184cbc3e9716a903655f71fe45b85d2fb6^ 126fb1184cbc3e9716a903655f71fe45b85d2fb6
:100644 100644 fe0ee17e5f995686fa5c1ec342b6f4048774b17a 595a93fb5264c1c21c570fa1b8dfb26adfe42fba M  extras/package/macosx/VLC.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
:100644 100644 ace16e1aca6e96a2558f238ec4196a5434c538fc e10209ff496ad3b63ddda86dc6f8d5a394d58e74 M  modules/gui/macosx/Makefile.am
:100644 100644 5b86759b0bdf0cafd6770c018432577d966f426b 78366fd14655727bfde06f0fca60c95da38c7462 M  modules/gui/macosx/VLCFSPanelController.h
:100644 100644 ae7fce903d8514938ed9c7757f69d6fdaff66f15 b9bd614444e372027db0ba2ada92f79439ef1cfa M  modules/gui/macosx/VLCMainWindow.h
:100644 100644 07e698ecff1bc6397e48de836f3a346dd22c27c6 8d18a3b6e40d7f119306cf225c4f89fd80b31dfa R080   modules/gui/macosx/Windows.h    modules/gui/macosx/VLCVideoWindowCommon.h
:100644 100644 300c99d108fddea5c442a110c5f2af62129a955d 6a7e47ad16c057dd9aa5e62a5c354252f72a5b50 R085   modules/gui/macosx/Windows.m    modules/gui/macosx/VLCVideoWindowCommon.m
:100644 100644 704ed7e87b797a86fdc3c64bbf098f65f505dfb8 551e161c65a203d70bba75d83183afb2c0384985 C065   modules/gui/macosx/VLCApplication.h modules/gui/macosx/VLCWindow.h
:000000 100644 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 a92418f1667b626ce68c8ac75a90812bfe5e6f4b A  modules/gui/macosx/VLCWindow.m
:100644 100644 96b9f6761755a35a97f2bb9848ae25ec15b625ff d8537d7e7b8338ade96b998a293d6176e994ab1a M  po/POTFILES.in
```

Here, `R085` means a rename with similarity index 85%, and `C065` means a copy with similarity index 65%.

Thankfully, git also escapes problem characters:

```
$ dir
a.txt  b.txt  c\ c.txt  d\td.txt  e\ne.txt
$ printf "%15s\n" * | hexdump -C
00000000  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 61 2e 74 78 74 0a  |          a.txt.|
00000010  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 62 2e 74 78 74 0a  |          b.txt.|
00000020  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  63 20 63 2e 74 78 74 0a  |        c c.txt.|
00000030  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  64 09 64 2e 74 78 74 0a  |        d.d.txt.|
00000040  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  65 0a 65 2e 74 78 74 0a  |        e.e.txt.|
$ git diff-tree --find-copies-harder -r -M HEAD^ HEAD
:100644 100644 f57a61465c88a387f1f9f2c6d8ef2fc6664da7ea f57a61465c88a387f1f9f2c6d8ef2fc6664da7ea R100   a.txt   "a\ta.txt"
:100644 100644 ae6ead370af774b6c9341805dd8d40a139fb8ac6 68005d4639648fcef9afc82108baa5979f5bcabf C089   b.txt   "b\nb.txt"
:100644 100644 9f429e1ad06183294f3b2c586481f919fe4d1875 80eb29a464aba1d866b8248843aaa0db11bd98e2 R079   "d\td.txt"  d.txt
:100644 100644 8aedf86ace0da13975de33a62e27f092a254b045 8aedf86ace0da13975de33a62e27f092a254b045 C100   "e\ne.txt"  "e/e\te.txt"
```

In the above examples, filenames have tabs and newlines in them, so those need to be unescaped.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. However, I do not think it is yet a complete solution. If the file names have spaces in them, how can I reliably parse the rename information?

Comment: The hashes listed by `git diff-tree` appear to be blob hashes, and there is not a reliable way to get the filename since the filename is not part of the hash (two files with different names, but identical contents, will have this same hash).

Comment: The paths are tab-separated, spaces aren't a problem.

Comment: It is great that spaces in particular are not a problem, but TAB is a valid (albeit ill-advised) path character on POSIX. I am looking for a programmatic interface. Some git tools use "-z" to use NUL as a delimiter.

Comment: Well, then, if you're operating in the IT equivalent of a war zone you can [use the howitzer-proof `-z` which uses nuls as field terminators](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree#Documentation/git-diff-tree.txt--z).